# How get HardwareIdentification on Windows 7

Tags: c#

I try run this code, but it works only Windows 8-10 apps. How run this app in Winform App?

```
 var token = HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);
 var hardwareId = token.Id;
 var dataReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(hardwareId);

 byte[] bytes = new byte[hardwareId.Length];
 dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);

 return BitConverter.ToString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link to get more details : [here](http://jai-on-asp.blogspot.de/2010/03/finding-hardware-id-of-computer.html)

Here just an example:

Add assembly Reference first.

```
using System.Management;
```

The following code will retrieve the CPU ID (processor id):

```
ManagementObjectCollection mbsList = null;
ManagementObjectSearcher mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_processor");
mbsList = mbs.Get();

foreach (ManagementBaseObject o in mbsList)
{
    ManagementObject mo = (ManagementObject) o;

    string hId = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mo["ProcessorID"].ToString()));

    Console.WriteLine( hId);
}
```

Comment: your code return me "178BFBFF00100F53", but my code return me 03-00-BC-9E-05-00-0A-04-05-00-52-42-06-00-01-00-04-00-BE-06-04-00-1C-52-01-00-D4-1A-02-00-9E-7C-09-00-A2-69

Comment: See my corrections. The added part is just converting string to byte array and displays it as string.

Comment: Maxim, thx. i try you code but it returns me -42-46-45-42-46-42-46-46-30-30-30-33-30-36-41-39. Its very few. My code returns me 03-00-BC-9E-05-00-0A-04-05-00-52-42-06-00-01-00-04-00-BE-06-04-00-1C-52-01-00-D4‌​-1A-02-00-9E-7C-09-00-A2-69. Whats is incorrect?

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of getting the ID in your application? ASHWID is for UWP(Windows 8 apps) only.